# Node attaches url to static directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

If I have

```
app.get('/articles', function(req, res){
    res.render('views/public/postbycat.ejs',{id:req.params.id}); // load the index.ejs file
  })
```

It worked fine but with this

```
app.get('/articles/:id', function(req, res){
    res.render('views/public/postbycat.ejs',{id:req.params.id}); // eg /articles/12345679      })
```

the file is sent but instead of getting as i got in the first code 'css/style.cs', i get 'articles/css/style.cs' thereby leading to a wrong url of my image.

I have this in the server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

How can I fix this please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your css include doesn't have slash at the beginning of the path.
You have something like that: `css/style.css` 
it should be : `/css/style.css`